# Table moves to j-query specified position on button click - and then moves back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout

I need 4x4 buttons, and since I am new to HTML etc, I decided to use the easy, but deprecated Table. Due to me using a premade online-found Filebrowser, I had to change my Jquery-file to a newer version, that fit the Filebrowser (It won't open with the old one). The entire stylesheet changed, but that's not the real problem. When I press my button to open the Filebrowser, my table moves to what was originally specified by me in the JS-file. Then when I close the Filebrowser, it takes half a second to change back.  
Why doesn't my JS (jquery code) positioning apply from the beginning with the new Jquery?

```
<table id="tablediv">
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td id="buttonfield" style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">1</button></td>
    <td style="width:25%;"><button onclick="test()" type="button" id="button2"class="button">2</button></td>
    <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button3"class="button">3</button></td>
    <td style="width:25%;"><button  type="button" id="button4"class="button">4</button></td>
      </tr>


  <tr>
       <td id="buttonfield2" style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">5</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">6</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">7</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">8</button></td>
  </tr>

        <tr>
     <td id="buttonfield3" style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">9</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">10</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">11</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">12</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
       <td id="buttonfield4" style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">13</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">14</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">15</button></td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><button type="button" id="button1"class="button">16</button></td>
  </tr>
```

CSS:

```
#tablediv {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
}
#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}
table {
    width:100%;
}
```

JS:

```
totalWidth =$('body').width();
totalHeight=$('body').height();

menuLength=(totalWidth*0.03);

$("#tablediv").css("padding-top", menuLength+(menuLength*0.50));
$("#buttonfield").css("height", menuLength+menuLength);
$("#buttonfield2").css("height", menuLength+menuLength);
$("#buttonfield3").css("height", menuLength+menuLength);
$("#buttonfield4").css("height", menuLength+menuLength);
```

This is what the button does:

```
$("#button4").click(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("fileBrowser.html");
});
```

I changed my Jquery from Jquery.js (jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1) to

```
<link type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Original layout with old jquery file. (How it is supposed to look)
[image: original layout]
Layout with new Jquery
[image: layout with new jquery]
Now, the second I press a button (let's say button 1) to open the Filebrowser - the whole layout moves to this. When I close the Filebrowser, it gets back to picture2. 
[image: Onclick of button with new jquery]

What could be the problem? I rather would want to solve this, than trying to make 4x4 divs (like my first layout), because I'm just not the best at HTML-GUIs yet.

Comment: Could you post your whole file for the html/css/js? My guess would be that when you open the file browser it changes the height of the containing div for your table and since the height of the table (and cells) is specified with a % the rows adjust accordingly to a % of the parents current size. Explicitly setting the height of the tables parent div could solve the problem but without seeing the HTML/CSS/JS for the entire page it is hard to say.

Comment: Tables should not be used for layouts. You should be using FLOATS.

Comment: @diodeus I probably should. But as stated, I am not good at positioning yet. Can't you hint me how I could make buttons as the first picture shows?

Comment: @jasonTruluck Just added a tiny bit more to the JS. Everything relevant to the 4x4 tables is in the thread now. The thing is that I've set the table to what the JS specifies on initiation of the application. And as you see, the old jquery reacts to that. But the new Jquery only reacts to that onClick, even though the buttonclick code has nothing to do with the initiation part.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to the wonderful world of web development!

Now, the id attribute of an HTML element should be unique per page. Your td elements' id attributes are not unique.
You should also try to avoid inline styling, and use the css-file as much as you can.

I've made an example jsfiddle for you where I use jQuery to get the number of rows and columns in the table, and then setting the height and padding of the buttons. That way you can add or remove buttons as you please, and the jQuery code will make sure the buttons are evenly spread.

Note: This only works as long as there are an equal number of cells in each row.

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/erichfosse/Qqhh2/6/

Code:

HTML:

```
<table id="tablediv">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">1</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">2</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">3</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">4</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td><button type="button" class="button">5</button></td>
         <td><button type="button" class="button">6</button></td>
         <td><button type="button" class="button">7</button></td>
         <td><button type="button" class="button">8</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">9</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">10</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">11</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">12</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">13</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">14</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">15</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="button">16</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
#tablediv {
    width: 100%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var totalWidth = $('body').width();
var totalHeight = $('body').height();

var rows = $('tr').size();
var columns = $('td').size()/$('tr').size();

var distanceToNextButton = 8; // Adjust this to your needs
var leftOverVerticalSpace = 23; // Increase the number subtracted to make room for more stuff
var buttonHeight = (totalHeight/rows) - leftOverVerticalSpace; 
var buttonWidth = (totalWidth/columns) - distanceToNextButton;
var buttonVerticalPadding = (buttonHeight/2) - 8;
var buttonHorizontalPadding = (buttonWidth/2) - 8;

$(".ui-btn-inner").css("padding-top", buttonVerticalPadding);
$(".ui-btn-inner").css("padding-right", buttonHorizontalPadding/2);
$(".ui-btn-inner").css("padding-bottom", buttonVerticalPadding);
$(".ui-btn-inner").css("padding-left", buttonHorizontalPadding/2);
$(".ui-btn").css("height", buttonHeight);
$(".ui-btn").css("width", buttonWidth);
```

Comment: I made my upper panel div, so your JS-css settings didn't affect them. So now this solution is pretty close to perfect. But is there any way that I could've kept them as Buttons (the upper panel), without these ui-btn-inner and ui-btn affecting them? 

Also, the layout still moves a tiny tiny bit. But it's so little, that I find it acceptable.

Comment: jQuery mobile adds the classes to the buttons, so you'll have to override them with your own.

In most browsers you can right click an element, and then choose to "inspect" it. This will bring up the developer tools where you, among other things, can see which css rules that apply to the element.